# breakpoint will not be hit no symbols have been loaded for vs website

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm getting the subject error for breakpoints set on a vs 2010 website project.

When I view the modules window under Debug-->Windows-->Modules I see that it cannot find or open the PDB file for WebDev.WebHost40.dll -- it skips loading symbols for all other dlls.  I tried to fix this by using Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Symbols and checking Microsoft Symbol Servers, this fixed the cannot load symbols message in the module window, but it still wont debug and gives the same error message.  I've also tried deleting the temp Visual Studio files, rebuilt the project, closed and re-opened visual studio, and also rebooted machine.  Any other suggestions?  Has my project perhaps been corrupted and I start fresh with a new project?

Thanks

Comment: One more thing to try - perform a 'Clean' (and even go manually and delete the bin/debug and bin/release folders)

Comment: it doesnt have the Clean option in Debug menu -- I guess because its a website and not a web application.

Comment: it will debug on the start htm page, but no others

Comment: is the start page in the same directory and are the other pages being built there? Does that directory have the necessary permissions. e.g. try right clicking VS then run as admin then try debugging.

Comment: they are all in the same directory, and permissions are ok

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check - in Visual studio - right click the project and go to the build tab. Make sure you are running under debug mode. Also check the debugging settings and target platform are OK. There are also adanced build settings worth checking in this tab. You mention that the pdb file isnt being created? If it is, try deleting it and then it will be recreated by VS. If it isn't there is something wrong with the build settings. I would try some changes in the build tab to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a brand new solution, if you can debug that then there's something wrong with one of your projects. You then need to work out what's different between the working project and the broken one.

If you can't debug a new project either, then at least you know it's not your project, and time to reinstall VS (boo).