# debug multiple htm pages in visual studio website

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a visual studio 2010 website with one project.  All the pages are htm with dojo javascript (no aspx).  The problem I'm having is that I can only debug the start page.  When I try to set a break point on any other page I get an error the breakpoint will not currently be hit, no symbols have been loaded for the document.  Is this a limitation of visual studio javascript debugging?  Is there any way I can make this work?

I unsuccessfully tried the solutions provided in my other post ([breakpoint will not be hit no symbols have been loaded for vs website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437020/breakpoint-will-not-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-vs-website)). But was wondering if the problem I'm having with this is because I'm using only javascript.  Maybe I should use a different software the vs for javascript development?

Thanks

Pete

Comment: do the breakpoints fill in when you load the other pages? could be that they will show they are not loaded when you are on the home page as they have not yet loaded until you get to the page they are on?

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of limitations, best way to debug javascript is using the f12 built in tool for all browsers (chrome or firefox are best, as always IE is um $#!^)

you can breakpoint and run code in the console as you are debugging, you can also inline edit the JS and then save that over the current file.

hope this helps

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is that I'm using dojo set to fill the center content pane with an htm page.  The page I'm trying to debug isnt visible to chrome f12 either -- only the main page